# Hibernate LocalSessionFactoryBean, setMappingDirectoryLocations doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Spring 5 and Hibernate 5 together, and I'm configuring Hibernate mapping files in:
`org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` like this in my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations" value="com/myorg/division/myapp/model" />
```

But I'm getting this error run-time error when I deploy the WAR file to my local Weblogic server:

```
Deployment Message : weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/com/
myorg/division/myapp/model] cannot be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?
```

Comment: Did you try using packagesToScan???

Comment: @WilderValera That's something different

Comment: mappingDirectoryLocations seems to be loading files from the resources folder. That's why I asked about packagesToScan

Comment: @WilderValera Oh ok, so how do I use packagesToScan?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myorg.division.myapp.model" />
```